# Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\login.php on line 927

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am having problem login out and destroying session created. the feed back are:

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\login.php on line 927


Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\login.php:241) in C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\login.php on line 927


Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\login.php on line 928


Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\login.php:241) in C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\login.php on line 929
```

The referenced code in those line are
Line 241 to 275:

```
<?php
require("include/dbinfo.php");
$link=mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass)or die(errorReport(mysql_error()));
mysql_select_db($db,$link)or die(errorReport(mysql_error()));
if(!isset($_GET['pid']))
{
    echo "<div><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/style01.css\">";
    $username=$_COOKIE['username'];
    $sessionid=$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
    $row=mysql_query("select * from session where username='$username' and id='$sessionid'");
    if(!empty($row)&&(mysql_num_rows($row)))
    {
        $result=mysql_query("select * from employee where Employee_ID='$username'");
        if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $name=$row['Name'];
            $eid=$row['Employee_ID'];
            $dept=$row['Dept_No'];
            $gender=$row['Gender'];
            $contact=$row['Contact'];
            $dob=$row['DOB'];
            $add=$row['Address'];
            echo "<h3>Personal Details</h3>";
            echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=0 style=\"margin:5px 0px 0px -3px;\">";
            echo "<tr><td width=5%>Name: </td><td width=50%>$name</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Employee ID: </td><td>$eid</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Date of Birth: </td><td>$dob</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Department: </td><td>$dept</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Contact: </td><td>$contact</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Gender: </td><td>$gender</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Address: </td><td>$add</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
    echo "</div>";
```

Line 920 to 931:

```
else if(isset($_GET['pid'])&&(strcmp($_GET['pid'],"logout")==0))
{
    $username=$_COOKIE['username'];
    $sessionid=$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
    if(mysql_query("select * from session where username='$username' and id='$sessionid'"))
    {
        $result=mysql_query("delete from session where username='$username'and id='$sessionid'");
        setcookie("username",$_POST['username'],time()-3600);
        unset($_SESSION['PHPSESSID']);
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    echo "</div>";
```

Please, what is wrong here?

Comment: You use $_SESSION variable but you didn't start any session, am I wrong ? you should add a session_start(); on the top of your document if there isn't any otherwhere ?

Answer (score 0):

- `Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\login.php on line 927`
  You're using `$_POST['username']` but I think you meant to be using `$username`
- `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\login.php:241) in C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\login.php on line 927`
  You can only modify the cookie before you echo anything. You can either not echo until you have modified this or catch any output using `ob_start`.
- `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\login.php on line 928`
  You are missing a `session_start` call.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have initiated a session with <?php
session_start();?>, change $_POST['username'] $username. I later discover i still have this error message: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (output started at......) so i decided to use: <?php
    ob_start();
?> at the begining of the script and

Answer (score 0):

Your session is not started, or started too late : you should start it with `session_start()` at the beginning of your code.

Since sessions set a cookie on the user's browser, the http response must not be sent to the browser when you call `session_start()` or `setcookie()`.

Basically, you should  avoid calling `echo` before calling `session_start()`or `setcookie()`

If you can't do this in your current code, you can use [Output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to prevent `echo`to send your response before the setcookie() function is called.

Comment: I tried starting the session at the beginning of the code but it brought error report again. Is there a way i can: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require' (T_REQUIRE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\login.php on line 243

Comment: This new error doesn't seem related : parse errrors mean that the code is not syntaxically correct on line 243  of your script (the line 243 contains the first "unexpected caracter", but it may be due to an error at the end of the previous line). Maybe a missing `;` ?.

Answer (score 0):

You unset  `unset($_SESSION['PHPSESSID']);` but you dont have `session_start()` to start it. Please put it at the top right after the `<?php` tags.
Because you are not posting the `username` value but its in the cookie, and you defined it as `$username`, Change this

```
setcookie("username",$_POST['username'],time()-3600);
```

To

```
setcookie("username",$username,time()-3600);
```